# Custom PostProcessor for search results from ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am currently using elasticsearch 5.0, and I wondered if its possible to add post hooks for the search hits from the query. Is there any way to create a pipeline for search results, similar to the kind of pipeline that can be defined for ingestion.

The requirement is to apply further filtering on the retrieved, using custom logic.

Based on my research, I found two ways :

1. Leverage the `post_filter` as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) . But again, didn't really find any way to write a custom post_filter.
2. Use  [SearchOperationListener](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5.0/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/shard/SearchOperationListener.java). Need to understand how to hook it into the existing query parsers.