# Generate multiple docs from one doc in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to generate multiple documents from one document in ES in just a query. For instance:

Original document:

```
"_source":{
    "name": "Name1",
    "values": [100,200,300]    
}
```

Generated documents for the golden query:

```
"_source":{
    "name": "Name1",
    "value": 100,
    "sequence":1    
}


"_source":{
    "name": "Name1",
    "value": 200,
    "sequence":2    
}


"_source":{
    "name": "Name1",
    "value": 300,
    "sequence":3   
}
```

My worry is the space, I'm ok with CPU and memory. That means I don't want to store my docs the way the query will give.

@Val

Comment: If this is run by a query, how will space affect it ?

Comment: Not the way it usually works. If you need this in your application, I guess that is the place I would put it. So run the query and do something with the result within your application.

Comment: @aclokay The point is: having the doc this way I can save space knowing I'll have more work in the CPU and memory.

Comment: @JettroCoenradie thanks, the thing is that ES will be receiving request from Grafana and this former needs things like the documents I want to generate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to find a query to do what you want.  Elastic stores and returns documents.  You can filter out what you want specifically returned about a document, but whatever it returns is going to still be a document it stores.  The returned result set has the actual document as an integral part of the return:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 0.2876821,
    "_source": {
      "name": "Name1",
      "values": [
        100,
        200,
        300
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I'm not entirely sure of your goal, but the closest you could probably get is an aggregation on the values to show what documents meet those values.

```
{
  "size" : 0,
  "aggs" : {
    "values" : {
      "terms" : {
        "size" : 10,
        "field" : "values"
      },
      "aggs" : {
        "hits" : {
          "top_hits" : {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem with this will be that `top_hits` is not meant for returning large result sets per bucket, just the most relevant.  So depending on what you are trying to do, you may either have to store them individually, or do post processing yourself to create a result per value.

Comment: Thanks. This link can give us more light: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40473431/custom-postprocessor-for-search-results-from-elasticsearch) _italic_ **bold** `code`